# Check if two selectors elements exist and have the same value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, sidebar

Consider this code:

```
if ( $('.sidebar-primary, .sidebar-secondary').css('float') === 'left' ) {
```

It gives me a true even if `.sidebar-secondary` does not even exist in the HTML. Why is that and how do I make this work even if the .sidebar-secondary sometimes does not exist?

Comment: You should check one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) says:

> [.css()]Get the value of a style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.

So only the first element of the array is considered. You need something like:

```
var every = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.every);

var isFloatLeft = every($('.sidebar-primary, .sidebar-secondary'), function(node) {
    return $(node).css('float') === 'left'
});

console(isFloatLeft);
```

Unfortunately jQuery doesn't have any `every` methods, luckily JavaScript (ES5 specs) does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Notice that is a kind of generic approach in case you need to check multiple elements. For only two you can just compare them directly:

```
isFloatLeft = $('.sidebar-primary').css('float') === 'float' && 
              $('.sidebar-secondary').css('float') === 'float;
```

Comment: this this is about the css() and not about having comma separated selectors? Meaning this would work with other things?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, however this will works also with other things rather than `css` method. Let's say you want to check if all the element have the same content, you can use the same approach, replacing `return $(node).css('float') === 'left'` with `return node.textContent === "foo"`, for example. If some element doesn't exist it won't be part of the collection, therefore will be ignored and the code will works – the ones with `every` I mean.

Comment: You said jQuery has no `every` method what about `each`?

Comment: What i meant was if I would use `if ( $('.sidebar-primary, .sidebar-secondary').something()` would that also not work / stop after the first element, because what you quoted above is for css() specifically. Anyway I will check that myself later I guess, thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, `each` returns the `jQuery` object itself, in order to chaining, not a boolean. You can stop the iteration with `return false` but you can't return `true` or `false`: you need in that case an external variable to set, and usually I prefer to avoid this such dependencies unless there is no better solution. If you don't care, you can use `each` too.

Comment: About the `something()` things: it depends by the implementation: if the node doesn't exist, the `something()` method will be executed only on the existing nodes of course. But depends on the method, they can be executed on all existing elements, or only on the first existing element: `each` is part of the first category, where `css` and `attr` are part of the second.

Answer (score 1):

"Get the value of a style property for the **first element** in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element."(http://api.jquery.com/css/)..

You should try:

```
if (
   $('.sidebar-primary').css('float') === 'left' && 
   $('.sidebar-secondary').css('float') === 'left' ){
   // Your code here...
}
```

Comment: remember that code tests if both of them have `float` set as `left`

Answer (score 0):

It will match the first selector, so if you have `.sidebar-primary` only this one will be evaluated.
To solve this you have to compare one by one.

Take a look the following [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jDejM/) to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Break your condition statement into parts:

```
if ($('.sidebar-primary').css('float') === 'left' && $('.sidebar-secondary').css('float') === 'left')) {
   //Do your stuff!
}
```

Or, if you have a large list of elements you want to check against:

```
function CheckFloat() {
    $('.sidebar-primary, .sidebar-secondary').each(function(i, e) {
      if (e.css('float') != 'left') {
          return false;
      }
    });

    return true;
}
```